# How can I display leaderboards (reset once a week) with branch.io

Tags: android, ios, mobile, deep-linking, branch.io

I've got a question regarding branch.io referral program. Is it possible to develop the following userstory:

- each user starts with a default bucket
- the user signs up and can add a profile image (increase credits), follow us on facebook (+credits)
- once a week we trigger a "reset" and the credits in the bucket of all users are reset (=0); we can also add a new bucket if needed.
- during the "competition" we want to display a leaderboard of the "best" users with the most referred installs.

So, this was just a brief explanation. But I hope you get the idea. Is this possible (via iOS, Android, Webhooks and API)?

Question #2: Is it possible to display this leaderboard also on the frontend and increase credits if the web-app user does something special?

Answer (score 2):

Austin from branch here. To be honest, this is a pretty custom use of the out of the box referrals program we provide.

There's no specific API that does exactly what you want, but you can create it by storing updates in realtime as credits are updated to Branch users. However, this will require you to host this on your own servers.

However, if you want to display credits and referrals for an individual user, we have a whole plug and play guide for it here:

Show Referrals for a single user: https://dev.branch.io/recipes/referral_links_with_incentives/ios/#showing-referrals

API Documentation: https://dev.branch.io/references/http_api/

Wish there was a better solution for this, but hopefully this helps answer your question!

Austin